# How to run Django task periodically on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, celery, worker, periodic-task

I have a Django application deployed on Heroku using 1 web dyno, basically just hosting a website where people can signup, then the app can send emails to those people.

Right now I send all the emails manually; I go in django shell everytime on heroku server, and call function like `a.send_customized_email()`

I'm wondering how to make a scheduler thing to send emails periodically without me coding in commands in the backend everytime?

I heard about Django celery, but how to integrate it exactly? Should I fire up another dyno? What should be the configuration files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` file you can use

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    'add-every-monday-morning': {
        'task': 'a.tasks.send_customized_email()',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```

and in your `tasks.py` file you can specify what send_customized_email() is